# pgf path decoration with corners awareness

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

I try to create pgf decoration that will be able to tell in each segment whether the its start is a sharp corner on the input path, but I can't figure how to do this.

Take for example the following MWE. It decorates path with curves. When it reaches a corner and there is no room for another curve, it just draws a simple line and draws a curve after the corner. How can I make it to draw another simple line after the corner and only than to start the curves?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}


\pgfdeclaredecoration{examp}{A}
{   
    \state{A}[width=4mm,auto corner on length=4mm]
    {
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0mm}{0}}{\pgfpoint{2mm}{5mm}}{\pgfpoint{4mm}{0}};
    }
    %
    \state{final}
    {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast};
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decoration={examp,path has corners=true},decorate] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can create a state B which always starts with a straight line in each segment. And run A once and B all the way afterwards. But there are always strange cases that cannot be handled with a one-size-fits-for-all solution.

Comment: @percusse I see you left a comment while I was looking this up. I'm not sure if my answer is exactly what you had in mind or not. If it is, let me know that I should delete it so that you can answer. (Well, you can answer anyway, of course, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: @cfr As you know very well we don't compete here. It's a nice answer so no reason to delete. And I think I meant that way. Can you include some arcs and `-|` on the same path to see whether it goes through ?

Comment: @percusse Indeed. That's why I said it. I've extended the example. I'm not sure that is quite what it should do in the case of an `arc` but it seems to do something reasonable for `|-` and the `curveto` examples. I guess TiKZ splits the `arc` into distinct input segments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[I see that while I was looking this up, percusse left a comment. I'm not sure if this is exactly what percusse had in mind or not. If so, let me know that I should delete this.]

[image: sharp corner]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\newlength{\prelength}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{examp}{A}
{
    \state{A}
      [
        width=4mm,
        switch if input segment less than={4mm to B},
      ]
    {
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0mm}{0}}{\pgfpoint{2mm}{5mm}}{\pgfpoint{4mm}{0}};
    }
    \state{B}
      [
        width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
        repeat state=0,
        next state=C,
        persistent precomputation={%
          \setlength{\prelength}{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
        },
      ]
    {
      \pgflineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast};
    }
    \state{C}
      [
        width=\prelength,
        repeat state=0,
        next state=A,
      ]
    {
      \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{\prelength}{0}};
    }
    \state{final}
    {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast};
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decoration={examp},decorate] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3) |-  cycle;
\draw[decoration={examp},decorate, xshift=40mm] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3) arc (90:-90:1.5) [out=135, in=45] to cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sharp corners with |- and arcs]

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Ido